# I want to replace my paypal email address with some text on Paypal Checkout

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-buttons

I have a problem with PayPal custom checkout. I want to replace my PayPal email address on the custom shopping cart checkout form:

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourmail@gmail.com">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test">
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.00">
   <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="2">
   <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

How can I do this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the receiving PayPal account to a Business account, and choose a business name.

See https://www.paypal.com/gf/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-upgrade-from-a-personal-premier-account-to-a-business-account-faq1317

Comment: Let me try, sir